# Selenium Grid: MaxSessions vs MaxInstances

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I was wondering if anybody could shed some light on a `Selenium` question that has been giving us a bit of head scratching.

We're confused on meaning of `MaxSession` and `MaxInstances` of Selenium Grid.  We think that the `MaxSession` is the total number of test sessions that can run on a single node.  And we also think that the `MaxInstances` is the total number of browsers that a test can open.

Or is `MaxInstances` the total number of browsers available to the node?

**The command that we are using is:**

```
java -Xrs -jar selenium-server.jar -role node -port 44506 -hub http://localhost:44500
/grid/register -firefoxProfileTemplate SeleniumProfile -timeout 300000 -browser 
"browserName=firefox,maxInstances=10,platform=ANY,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser 
"browserName=chrome,maxInstances=10,platform=ANY,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```

We think the way we are using our node (above) is 5 concurrent test sessions by default.

**Does each test have 20 browsers available to it?**

**Or does each test session share the 20 browsers (10 chrome/10 FF) in a pool - with the other test sessions?**

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Nice question....i would say it's bit confusing.... But will try to answer it in simple terms..

***MaxInstances*** This says....how many instances of same version of browser can run over the Remote System.

```
For example, i have a FF12,IE and i declared the command as follows
-browser browserName=firefox,version=12,maxInstances=5,platform=LINUX
-browser browserName=InternetExplorer,version=9.0,maxInstances=5,platform=LINUX
```

So i can run 5 instances of Firefox 12 and as well as 5 instances of IE9 at the same time in remote machine. So total user can run 10 instances of different browsers (FF12 & IE9) in parallel.

***MaxSession*** This says....how many browsers (*Any Browser and any version*) can run in parallel at a time in the remote system.  So this overrides the Max Instances settings and can restrict the number of browser instances that can run in parallel.

```
For above example, when maxSession=1 forces that you never have more than 1 browser running. 

With maxSession=2 you can have 2 Firefox tests at the same time, or 1 Internet Explorer and 1 Firefox test).
```

***Irrespective of what MaxInstances you have defined.***

For more clear info do visit -  https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/grid.html

Comment: Is it actually possible to have just one Session when running many nodes? I create a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095385/selenium-maxsession-for-all-nodes

Comment: So as 'MaxSession' related to whole grid , it  should be used with hub config . isn't it ? and 'MaxInstances' as it is related to number of instances of particular browser , it should be used with node config . Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @sjethvani no, it has nothing to do with the grid. A grid is basically a delegator, it receives tests which it then distributes among its nodes. A single node, however, can also execute multiple tests in parallel. Both "MaxSessions" and "MaxInstances" are node attributes - MaxInstances limits the number of tests that can be executed in parallel with a specific browser on the respective node. MaxSession, however, limits the number of tests that can be executed in parallel on a node, regardless of which browser they use.

Answer (score 6):

To expand upon [Anuragh27crony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13723831/5884126), I've drawn up a quick diagram:

[image]

If this is your node config, then you can execute at most 5 tests in parallel, for example in the following combinations:

- 3 * chrome, 2 * firefox
- 2 * chrome, 2 * firefox, 1 * edge
- 5 * edge
- 3 * chrome

The following combinations are NOT possible:

- 4 * chrome (exceeds Chrome maxInstances)
- 6 * edge (exceeds maxSessions)
- 3 * chrome, 3 * firefox (exceeds maxSessions)

As mentioned by Anuragh, MaxInstances applies to a specific browser, while MaxSessions applies to the entire node.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation in [Configuring the nodes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes) by default, starting a *Selenium Grid Node* allows for concurrent usage of 11 browsers:

- 5 Firefox
- 5 Chrome
- 1 Internet Explorer

The maximum number of concurrent tests is set to 5 by default. To change this and other browser settings, you can pass in parameters to each `-browser` switch (each switch represents a node based on your parameters). If you use the `-browser` parameter, the default browsers will be ignored and only what you specify command line will be used.

---

### maxInstances

[maxInstances](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) is an optional parameter which can be passed through the `-browser` optional parameter.

### Usecase 1

To configure a *Selenium Grid Node* for **20** instances of *Firefox version=X.Y.Z* you can use the following solution:

- Command:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=20,platform=WINDOWS
  ```
- Node Console Logs:

  ```
  C:\Utility\SeleniumGrid>java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=20,platform=WINDOWS
  16:54:11.843 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
  16:54:12.003 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 6318
  2020-02-14 16:54:12.523:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1022ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  16:54:12.860 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
  16:54:12.974 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 6318
  16:54:12.974 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid nodeis up and ready to register to the hub
  16:54:13.161 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
  16:54:13.765 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register
  16:54:13.962 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
  ```
- Grid Console Snapshot:

[image: GidNodeFirefox20]

### Usecase 2

To configure a *Selenium Grid Node* for **10** instances of *Firefox version=A.B.C*  and **20** instances of *Chrome version=X.Y.Z* you can use the following solution:

- Command:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS -browser browserName=chrome,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=20,platform=WINDOWS
  ```
- Grid Console Snapshot:

[image: GidNodeFirefox10Chrome20]

---

### -maxSession

[-maxSession](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) is also an optional parameter which can be passed as a main parameter to configure the maximum number of browsing contexts that can run in parallel on a particular node. This is different from the `maxInstance` of supported browsers (Example: For a node that supporting Firefox version A.B.C, Firefox version P.Q.R  and Chrome version X.Y.Z, **maxSession=1** will ensure that you never have more than 1 browser running. With `maxSession=2` you can have 2 Firefox tests executing at the same time, or 1 Firefox and 1 Chrome test).

Example:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,version=A.B.C,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=P.Q.R,maxInstances=10,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=X.Y.Z,maxInstances=20,platform=WINDOWS" -maxSession 2
```

- Grid Console Snapshot:

[image: maxSession]

Answer (score 0):

`MaxInstances`: this gives you more slots per node, For example, `MaxInstances=5` will allow a maximum of 5 browsers per node

`MaxSession`: sets the maximum amount of tests that can run at the same time in a node. 
if `MaxInstances=5`, then MaxSession should also be at least 5.

see more at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium