# Protractor multiple browsers in sequence

Tags: protractor

Forgive me if this was asked before, but I could not find it.

How could I run my test suites in different browser's one after another. Meaning, run tests in chrome, close chrome, run tests in IE, close IE etc..

I am aware of multiCapabilities, but that seems to be for parallel only.

Thank-you

Comment: why would you do that? it's so much faster when parallel.

Comment: Because it is user based app and user can only be logged in once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the `maxSessions` option will fit your need.

Add this line in your Protractor config:

```
maxSessions: 1
```

See [reference config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fbfc72bad15667990232bb9ff1da503e03d16230/referenceConf.js#L73) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22009321/3049002).