# Protractor: Multiple browser instance tests fail where Single Instance tests pass

Tags: angularjs, cordova, integration, protractor, ionic-framework

I'm testing an Ionic application. When the app is run in the browser, the console does show that cordova.js is missing - which is right, but it doesn't break the application.

As long as I run my tests with a single browser instance, the missing files does not cause my tests to fail. Here is my configuration and spec files:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  suites: {
    test: 'e2e/test.spec.js'
  },
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
            binary: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Stable.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
            args: [],
            extensions: [],
        }
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100');
  }
};
```

Here is the test file:

```
describe('First test', function(){
it('just verifies that everything loads correctly', function() {
      expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

The above works without errors. But opening a second browser instance causes a fail:

```
describe('First test', function(){
  var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
  browser2.get('http://localhost:8100');
  var element2 = browser2.element;
it('just verifies that everything loads correctly', function() {
      expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

With the error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: unknown error: cordova is not defined
```

Comment: Could you check the following: 1. move `browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100');` from `onPrepare` to your test - into the `describe`; 2. replace `browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100');` with `browser.get('http://localhost:8100');`? Thanks.

Comment: Removing the .driver from the browser.driver.get causes any test to fail immediately whether the .get call is made in onPrepare or in Describe, even if I don't reference the second browser instance. I'll look into how I can call the .driver on the second instance.

Comment: Calling browser2.driver.get('http://localhost:8100') solves the problem! Hoorah. Thanks for point me in a direction.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to run instances one after the other? See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22009321/3049002