# Multiple browsers are opened, but only one browser running spec. other browsers are idle

Tags: protractor

I am trying to achieve parallel test execution in protractor. With the below mentioned code, I can open multiple browser. But only one browser running the spec, rest are just opened.Below is the snippet in config file

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
   'shardTestFiles': true,
   'maxInstances': 3
},
specs: ['Spec1.js',
        'Spec2.js',
        'Spec3.js'
        ],
```

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009321/running-e2e-tests-using-protractor-multicapabilities-config-but-limit-max-webdri

Comment: could you show entire config file, please. Are specs the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding count to the browser capabilities and maxSessions to the config file