# Run multicapabilities non-parallel

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I'm running some end-to-end tests on my website. I want to do these tests in both Chrome and Firefox, so I've configured the configuration file with `multicapabilities: [{browserName: 'chrome'}, {browserName: 'firefox'}]`. But when running the tests the two browser instances interfere with each other because sometimes Chrome does an action with will fail the Firefox tests.

**My question:**
Is it possible to not run the two browser instances in parallel? Instead I first want Chrome to do the tests, then when Chrome is finished, Firefox should start. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do MaxSessions = 1 in you config file. This limits the number of browser instances that can run in parallel. Beautifully explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723349/selenium-grid-maxsessions-vs-maxinstances/13723831#13723831) on StackOverflow. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: If I add `maxSessions: 1` with a `s` it works just the way I want! Thanks! :)

Comment: Great :) Edited the answer to fix the typo. Could you please accept the answer then!