# Selenium -maxSession for all Nodes

Tags: testing, selenium, protractor

We are using Selenium testing with protractor. For some tests we need to serialize the testing, so that maximum one Browser (in our case it's also an user) can be active. It's possible to limit the sessions with `-maxSession` parameter, but that just limits it for the current node. Is there a possibility to do that globally for every node or to start the nodes one after each other?

Answer (score 0):

oh well it was easier than I thought. Parameter `maxSessions: 1` in protractor.conf seems to work also with many nodes.