# How to run multiple selenium processes at a time with nightwatch?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch to run tests in parallel. I would like to be able to run multiple tests at a time in different selenium processes. How can I accomplish that?

What I did is create a selenium hub:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /home/jenkins-user/log/selenium.log  -role hub &
```

And when each test runs, I create a node:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /home/jenkins-user/log/selenium.log  -role node  -browser browserName=chrome -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register &
```

Unfortunately, this prevents me from running nightwatch tests in parallel.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're not using the native parallel support available (and are instead trying to do something outside the scope of what constitutes "normal" parallel test running for Nightwatch). If using a single selenium session for each test which is run and tests distributed per CPU (http://nightwatchjs.org/getingstarted#basic-settings) you will have one selenium session per test, per CPU. Is that not what you desire?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to start multiple selenium processes? You should not do that.

Check my answer for similar question: [Running multiple nightwatch instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721599/running-multiple-nightwatch-instances/38963965#38963965)