# Protractor could not find Angular on page when using selenium chrome node in headless mode

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm using the protractor instructions to establish that I can use my headless browsers.

So as per instructions...

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://seleniumhub:4444/wd/hub',
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: [
                "--headless",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                // chrome will crash without this
                '--headless',
                "--disable-gpu",
            ]
        }

    }
  ],

  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
  },
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

**todo-spec.js**

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
it('should add a todo', function() {
browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

// You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
});
});
```

From within my node 8.8.1 container I run

```
./node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js
```

Standard stuff really and really vanilla as I wanted to find what the culprit is.

When the tests run firefox passes and chrome fails with

> E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page https://angularjs.org/ : retries looking for angular exceeded

Any clues / ideas / suggestions?

My "seleniumhub" is a dockerised selenium grid with a firefox and a chrome node. Everything is on version 3.6.0.

To sum up the versions...

- Node 8.8.1 (docker)
- Selenium Hub 3.6.0 (docker)
- Selenium Chrome Node 3.6.0 (docker)
- Selenium Firefox Node 3.6.0 (docker)
- Protractor 5.2.0

Also here's my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  seleniumhub:
    image: selenium/hub:${SELENIUM_VERSION}
    networks:
      - private
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    environment:
    # As integer, maps to "maxSession"
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 10
    # In milliseconds, maps to "newSessionWaitTimeout"
      GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT: -1
    # As a boolean, maps to "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent"
      GRID_THROW_ON_CAPABILITY_NOT_PRESENT: 'true'
    # As an integer
      GRID_JETTY_MAX_THREADS: -1
    # In milliseconds, maps to "cleanUpCycle"
      GRID_CLEAN_UP_CYCLE: 5000
    # In seconds, maps to "browserTimeout"
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 0
    # In seconds, maps to "timeout"
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 30
    # Debug
      GRID_DEBUG: 'false'
    depends_on:
      - webserver

  firefoxnode:
    image: selenium/node-firefox${SELENIUM_DEBUG}:${SELENIUM_VERSION}
    networks:
      - private
    volumes:
      - /dev/urandom:/dev/random
      - .:/tmp/app:cached
    depends_on:
      - seleniumhub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: seleniumhub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723349/selenium-grid-maxsessions-vs-maxinstances
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 10
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 10

  chromenode:
    image: selenium/node-chrome${SELENIUM_DEBUG}:${SELENIUM_VERSION}
    networks:
      - private
    volumes:
      - /dev/urandom:/dev/random:ro
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm:ro
      - .:/tmp/app:cached
    depends_on:
      - seleniumhub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: seleniumhub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723349/selenium-grid-maxsessions-vs-maxinstances
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 10
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 10

  node:
    depends_on:
      - seleniumhub
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the  stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the culprit was the /dev/urandom and /dev/shm shares.
If they get removed everything works fine.

These were required with selenium 2.53.1 but not with the current version.

So enjoy the rest of configuration. It just works. :)